# Enquiry Form in MYSQL. IF statement within a mysql select statement, if field is empty, left join to get the replacement value

Tags: mysql, if-statement, left-join, case

I have a mysql problem

I populate my table with a user_id if a user is logged in. If they are not logged in I fill the table with their name, email and contact number. So in this scenario a user can submit an enquiry, if they are logged in/out.

I check if the enquiring user was logged in when they submitted the enquiry by checking if the user id is in the table. Therefore I can just fetch their name, email and contact from the l_users table.

Is there any mysql code that can achieve this for me?

So..

If user_id is empty, get the name, email and contact from the current table.
Else get the name, email and contact number from the l_users table using the user_id.

Can anyone help me with a solution?

I've seen the CASE function in mysql but i'm not familiar with it at all. I've got the logic. But I can't convert it into code :D

Thanks

Image of table below:

[image: field listing]

Answer:

```
$q =    "   SELECT  c.id,
                    c.user_id,  
                    IFNULL(u.fn, c.name) AS name, 
                    IFNULL(u.account_email, c.email) AS email, 
                    IFNULL(u.telephone, c.contact) AS contact, 
                    c.subject,
                    c.comment,
                    c.registered
                FROM l_contact_us c
                    LEFT JOIN l_users u 
                        ON c.user_id = u.id
            ORDER BY c.registered
        ";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ISNULL` function.

```
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT name FROM a_table WHERE user_id = @usr),
       (SELECT name FROM i_user WHERE user_id = @usr)) AS name,
       ISNULL((SELECT [address] FROM a_table WHERE user_id = @usr),
       (SELECT [address] FROM i_user WHERE user_id = @usr)) AS a_address
FROM DUAL
```

Or use a left outer join:

```
SELECT ISNULL(t1.name, t2.name) AS name,
       ISNULL(t1.address, t2.address) AS a_address
FROM a_table t1
       LEFT JOIN i_user t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
WHERE t1.user_id = @usr
```

Comment: or do I just left join the table anyway? Then check if the user_id is not null after I get the result?

Comment: Yes, left join. ISNULL will not permit you select more than one field

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice, i used the 2nd option involving the left join, it works well, please see the answer in the original question. Had to change ISNULL to IFNULL also. reputation++